# in the tableView when each cell is selected the stepper value should start from 0 for each cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

I have a table in one of view with many rows. And below the tableView i have a stepper which increments and decrements by clicking plus and minus on it. Now i want the logic for when i select a row,the default value of stepper should start with 0. but in my case,if i select a row,and increment the stepper to 3 then go to next row,the stepper has 3 value and not 0. Can anyone tell me how to do that?

Comment: Make the question clear. Add appropriate code also

Comment: not able to understand...

Comment: I have a table in one of view with many rows. And below the tableView i have a stepper which increments and decrements by clicking plus and minus on it. Now i want the logic for when i select a row,the default value of stepper should start with 0. but in my case,if i select a row,and increment the stepper to 3 then go to next row,the stepper has 3 value and not 0.

Comment: stepper value is different for different rows? I mean it could be for row1->1 row2->5...

Comment: Yes. I want it different but no fixed value. For each row i select, i want to increment or decrement the stepper but it should start incrementing from 0 value

Comment: Why do you just repeat your original question in the comment when asked to clarify? Can you please try to rephrase the question?

Comment: @MariusFalkenbergWaldal When asked for clarification, he added it as comment. That i have copied to the question

Comment: Ok. I still don't understand what the OP is after, though :-(

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is create a property to hold the stepper value in your custom table view cell.

```
@property (assign)float stepperValue;
```

Initialise it with zero. In `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` set the stepper value like

```
[self.stepper setValue:selectedCell.stpperValue];
```

So that the stepper will count from whatever value is previously used for the row. This is what i understood from the question(it is not clear).

Comment: sorry if the question is not clear. I cannot understand how to explain it. Actualy i dint want the stepper value to start from whatever it was previously.I wanted it to always start from zero. Anyway i have got the answer to it.Thankyou.